# Flutter InAppWebView catch Uri.path on 302 redirect

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I think question's title describes my problem well. I use InAppWebView, I want to catch `/logout` path. At the moment there's no link on the website, that would open logout path, so I change url in url bar and click enter. I can't just add logout button there, and I don't even know if it would fix the issue. I know there's 302 redirect on /logout and I'm redirected to `/login`. I see login path in logs, but can't see logout path. I need to implement something on logout, so I really need to somehow catch this logout path.

I use this code below, I tried to `print(uri!.host)` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, `onLoadStart` etc. but neither works for me. I know I can check if there's logout before `loadUrl()`, but it doesn't seem like a good solution for me in this case - there will be no url bar in the future and I'm not sure if normal logout button fix this issue(I'm not sure if it's loadUrl issue or 302 redirect issue. I could just install and configure nginx, create something simple with redirect, but I will get a new pc in less than a week, so I kinda don't want to go through this now to be honest. I'm sorry, I know this isn't good excuse, I'm just worried that I would spend a half of day to only check this, and maybe someone already know and can say what would happen. If not I think I would check this when I get the new pc and give an update on how it works.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (!kIsWeb && defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    await InAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: new MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
  InAppWebViewSettings settings = InAppWebViewSettings(
      useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      iframeAllow: "camera; microphone",
      iframeAllowFullscreen: true
  );

  PullToRefreshController? pullToRefreshController;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;
  final urlController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    pullToRefreshController = kIsWeb ? null : PullToRefreshController(
      settings: PullToRefreshSettings(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
          webViewController?.reload();
        } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
          webViewController?.loadUrl(
              urlRequest: URLRequest(url: await webViewController?.getUrl()));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Official InAppWebView website")),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                controller: urlController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                onSubmitted: (value) {
                  var url = WebUri(value);
                  if (url.scheme.isEmpty) {
                    url = WebUri("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + value);
                  }
                  webViewController?.loadUrl(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: url));
                },
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    InAppWebView(
                      key: webViewKey,
                      initialUrlRequest:
                      URLRequest(url: WebUri("https://inappwebview.dev/")),
                      initialSettings: settings,
                      pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
                      onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                        webViewController = controller;
                      },
                      onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                        setState(() {
                          this.url = url.toString();
                          urlController.text = this.url;
                        });
                      },
                      onPermissionRequest: (controller, request) async {
                        return PermissionResponse(
                            resources: request.resources,
                            action: PermissionResponseAction.GRANT);
                      },
                      shouldOverrideUrlLoading:
                          (controller, navigationAction) async {
                        var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                        if (![
                          "http",
                          "https",
                          "file",
                          "chrome",
                          "data",
                          "javascript",
                          "about"
                        ].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                          if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
                            // Launch the App
                            await launchUrl(
                              uri,
                            );
                            // and cancel the request
                            return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                          }
                        }

                        return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                      },
                      onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                        pullToRefreshController?.endRefreshing();
                        setState(() {
                          this.url = url.toString();
                          urlController.text = this.url;
                        });
                      },
                      onReceivedError: (controller, request, error) {
                        pullToRefreshController?.endRefreshing();
                      },
                      onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                        if (progress == 100) {
                          pullToRefreshController?.endRefreshing();
                        }
                        setState(() {
                          this.progress = progress / 100;
                          urlController.text = this.url;
                        });
                      },
                      onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                        setState(() {
                          this.url = url.toString();
                          urlController.text = this.url;
                        });
                      },
                      onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                        print(consoleMessage);
                      },
                    ),
                    progress < 1.0
                        ? LinearProgressIndicator(value: progress)
                        : Container(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              ButtonBar(
                alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                    onPressed: () {
                      webViewController?.goBack();
                    },
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                    onPressed: () {
                      webViewController?.goForward();
                    },
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                    onPressed: () {
                      webViewController?.reload();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ])));
  }
}
```

This code is from [Inappwebview.dev](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/webview/in-app-webview/)

Comment: It's `loadUrl` issue. It resolves a problem for me in my case, but I have no idea how to do this with `loadUrl` for people who might look into this thread in the future.